# Lightweight release of a very simple Qt program

Tags: qt, release-management

To enable others to run a simple Qt4 program, you needed to ship 12 MB worth of DLLs.
I recently upgraded to Qt5, and am shocked to see that it grew to over 41 MB.

This means, to release a simple GUI program, even just a "Hello World", and still remain under LGPL, it will be over 40 MB.

This is very inconvenient if I would like to make a simple but useful tool to (freely) distribute on the Internet, as it can't compete with other similar programs written with much harder-to-develop-in tools such as MS MFC or even winapi, which manage to be under 100 kB.

Is there any possibility to make a lightweight, minimalistic release of a simple Qt GUI application?

Comment: I would only distribute the dlls that are needed. For example in most of my Qt4 based applications I only need to distribute QtCore.dll and QtGUI.dll.

Comment: @drescherjm : yes, but Qt5 requires the ICU even if I don't use it.

Comment: @vsz ICU is only required for the webkit. You can configure your Qt build so it doesn't use it. Read [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30950).

Comment: You can try using UPX to compress your Qt DLL libraries and your binaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get too far when you don't compile your Qt yourself. For a simple Qt GUI app you need at least the Qt5Core and the Qt5Gui dll. They are not so big, However, the available binaries have a dependency to ICU. This lib is a bit large. If you don't need QWebKit you can disable ICU. There is probably some other stuff you can disable when you don't need it, but ICD is by far the biggest dependency.

And don't worry about the LGPL. You don't modify your libs. You just don't deliver the whole package. This is not what the LGPL demands. So it is perfectly fine just to deliver Qt5Core and Qt5Gui. Even when you configured and compiled your Qt5 yourself. You did not **change** the code of a lib.

Comment: I mentioned the LGPL because of dynamic vs. static linking... And I can't really distribute just "half of a DLL". So do you mean that for each of my projects I need to have a separate Qt build? For example, if I need QWebKit in one project, but not in another one...

Comment: Yes, I'd say you then need two separate Qt builds. But if you need QWebKit you won't get Qt small anyways. Static linking is not option. First I have never seen a working static link of Qt5. Second, the LGPL does not forbid static linking, but you must give the receiver an option to relink your code. So you'd have huger binaries **and** you have to deliver your object files, so relinking is possible.

Comment: One way to manage this (having different compiled Qt) is to have completely separate build trees and use relative paths to find Qt and other libraries. I have done this for quite some time now because of all the dependencies I have with the frameworks and libraries I use in my medical imaging research. I am however making use of CMake but I assume QMake will allow the same.

Comment: Even in this case I can't find a way to release a very minimalistic Qt program which is under 1 MB. I can see whole image editing tools which are not much bigger than 100 kB.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do static linking and remain LGPL-compliant. What you need to make available, then, are the object files that you linked with Qt. So that someone else can take their own, perhaps modified, Qt, and statically re-link it with your objects. That's the nominal way to deal with it.

For a reasonable example of how to comply, see the [QM Modeling Tool's compliance package](https://state-machine.com/qm/qt_lgpl.html).